# How to look up the version of the current plugin?

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

I have a plugin Foo version 1.2.3 whose implementation depends upon the plugin version (it looks up artifacts with the same version). Initially I tried looking up `${project.version}` but if Bar 2.3.4 invokes Foo 1.2.3 then obviously `${project.version}` resolves to 2.3.4 instead of 1.2.3.

How can I get a plugin to look up its own version number without hard-coding it twice (once in the pom, once in the code)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question:

```
import org.apache.maven.plugin.descriptor.PluginDescriptor;

[...]

PluginDescriptor pluginDescriptor = (PluginDescriptor) getPluginContext().
    get("pluginDescriptor");
String version = pluginDescriptor.getVersion();
```